# Ojdbc jar version for jdk1.7.0.79

Tags: java, ojdbc

I am working with Eclipse Luna version. I am facing trouble in connecting database.

I have doubt it might be a jar issue. Can anyone help.

Currently I am having JDK 1.7.0.79 and ojdbc 14.9.2.0.5. Also I tried ojdbc 5.

But both didn't work. Can anyone help which version to be used ?

Answer (score 1):

You should check out this table: https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/jdbc-faq-090281.html#01_03_1

In short: for JDK 7 you need either ojdbc7.jar or ojdbc6.jar, depends on the version of your database as well.

Comment: I am using oracle  Version 3.2.10.09.

Answer (score 0):

Issue got resolved. I was using sun.misc.BASE64Encoder() to decrypt my password from property file. But JDK 1.7 doesn't support this. So I changed the BASE64Encoder() to something else. That returned a null values for password. Thats why it didn't work. But now I change it back to sun.misc.BASE64Encoder() and using JDK 1.8. Now it's working fine.